# Not sure how to debug this fatal PHP error: Call to a member function createCustomer() on null

Tags: php, opencart-3, opencart-module

[Stripe Error in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TahLU.png)

Hi,

I purchased a Stripe gateway plugin for OpenCart 3.x.  The vendor support is not working/responding and I'm stuck trying to figure out why this error is being thrown.  I'm new to PHP and it looks like all the variables passed into the function are defined (none are null)..

If I hover my mouse over $this->Stripephp in VS, it shows NULL.  Does that mean the Stripe library hasn't loaded properly and the actual error is before this code?

Not sure how to debug from here.

I've tried isolating the variables to make sure they contain values.

Comment: The issue is that `$this->Stripephp` is null, but we have no idea why since we have no clue how you defined that property, or what happens to it at all before you're trying to use it. I would also recommend you to read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your function is in the same controller file where is your code with error use just

```
$this->createCustomer($myarraycode);
```

If the function in corresponding model file you must add route where the function is. Before load that model file.
When you asking please paste your code here. Do not use pictures with code.

Load model:

```
$this->load->model('extension/module/your_module_file');
```

Than:

```
$this->model_extension_module_your_module_file->createCustomer($myarraycode);
```